# Is it possible to split a Discord.py bot across multiple files?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have my Discord bot in one file (bot.py) and since it has many commands, my help command has to explain every single command as the bot aims to be functional and also very user-friendly. As you can imagine, this takes up a ***lot*** of space. What I would like to do is have the main commands in bot.py, and have all the help commands in a separate file (help.py) Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Yes it's possible, take a look at [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html) and [extensions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/extensions.html). In your case use extensions, but you can also combine both.

Comment: Thank you very much, but a more detailed answer would be very helpful if possible as the documentation doesn't really provide examples or anything like that.

Comment: The docs does provide an [example](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks). I always suggest to look at [RoboDanny](https://github.com/Rapptz/RoboDanny/tree/rewrite/cogs), which was written by the author of discord.py to see the implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example of extensions

- File called `foo.py`

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.command()
async def baz(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Whatever")


def setup(bot):
    # Every extension should have this function
    bot.add_command(baz)
```

- Main file

```py
bot.load_extension("path.foo") # Path to the file, instead of using a slash use a period
```

- Cogs (can be in the main file)

```py
class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    def baz(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("something")

bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
```

---

Combining cogs and extensions

- `foo.py`

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    def baz(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("something")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(MyCog(bot))
```

- main file

```py
bot.load_extension("path.foo")
```

For more info take a look at the [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html) and [extensions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/extensions.html) introductions.

*Also I'm assuming you're using `commands.Bot` and you named your bot instance `bot`*

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been searching for ways to do this for a long time!