# Discord.py divide commands in multiple files

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to make a discord.py bot, but all the commands are in one unique file.
Is there any way that I can divide the commands in various .py files?
For example:
in the main.py file I have

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord, os, random, time, keep_alive, save
from discord.utils import get
from discord import Member

TOKEN = os.environ['DISCORD_TOKEN']

JOIN_ROLE = "Unverified"

prefix = "/"


intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(prefix, intents = intents)

bot.remove_command('help')


keep_alive.keep_alive()
bot.run(TOKEN)`
```

and in another file named help.py I have this:

```
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Help commands", description="Shows various help commands")
  embed.add_field(name="Show this help", value = "`/help`", inline = False)
  embed.add_field(name="Help random stuff", value="`/helprand`", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Help economy", value="`/helpeco`", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Help music", value = "`/helpmusic`", inline = False)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

is there any way with which I can link these 2 files, so that when I type /help it pops up the help command instead of giving me an error?

Thanks to everyone that will help me

Comment: What error are you referring to?

Comment: when I try to do the /help command it says that the command doesn't exist, but it's in the file called help.py

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to split a Discord.py bot across multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66662756/is-it-possible-to-split-a-discord-py-bot-across-multiple-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html)

For example, in `help.py`, you create a class which inherits from `commands.Cog` and contains a `commands.command`:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class HelpCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @commands.command()
    async def help(self, ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Help commands", description="Shows various help commands")
        embed.add_field(name="Show this help", value = "`/help`", inline = False)
        embed.add_field(name="Help random stuff", value="`/helprand`", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Help economy", value="`/helpeco`", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Help music", value = "`/helpmusic`", inline = False)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

and then in your main file, you add the `HelpCog` to your bot:

```py
from help import HelpCog
...
bot = commands.Bot(prefix, intents = intents, help_command=None)
bot.add_cog(HelpCog(bot))
```

and remove the following line, because it's better to remove the default help command in the initialization of the `commands.Bot`:

```py
bot.remove_command("help")
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about specific discord development, but in standard python parlance, what you are describing is the difference between modules and packages. e.g.

This:

```py
# foo.py
def bar():
    print("bar")

def baz():
    print("baz")
```

Would be imported similarly to:

```py
# foo/__init__.py
from foo.bar import bar
from foo.baz import baz

# foo/bar.py
def bar():
    print("bar")

# foo/baz.py
def baz():
    print("baz")
```

Where in both cases you could import as `from foo import bar, baz`.